# Kura: Export Plug-in throws Nullpointer Exception

Tags: nullpointerexception, eclipse-plugin, osgi, equinox

I am working on the Kura/osgi "Hello World Example" from the [Kura website](http://eclipse.github.io/kura/doc/hello-example.html) to develop my first osgi bundle.

When I want to export the project as described (export - Deployable plug-ins and fragments) , I get the following:

> An internal error occurred during: "Export Plug-ins".
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Unfortunately there is no more information.

This seems to be the same as described and "solved"(?) [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=438652)
But I do not really get what to do to solve the problem.
I am using:
Win 7 (64),
Eclipse Luna,
Equinox 3.8.1 (as used in Kura downloads)

Thanks for support!

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: Unfortunately not... it is the only thing I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: Although the Eclipse Plug-Ins Developer Environment (PDE) in Eclipse Luna seemed to be installed already, it did not work properly. Reinstalling PDE worked fine for me